# resizable serial console window?

Tags: serial-console

When using the serial console of my system I always end up with `$COLUMNS=80` and `$LINES=24`.

While I can change these variables manually it is somewhat annoying to do this any time when the client side terminal window has been resized.

Usually I'm connecting to the console using `screen /dev/mytty baudrate`.

Changing the `$TERM` environment variable to "screen" or "xterm" does not help.

Will I need to call `getty` with some of those instead of vt100?

Needless to say that all of this works fine, when I connect to the same machine using ssh.

Answer (score 45):

Like the commentators before me mentioned there is no alternative to calling `resize` after every command, if you don't have this command and you don't want to install a package where it's in (`xterm`), here are two POSIX shell script that do the same using ANSI terminal escape codes:

```sh
res() {

  old=$(stty -g)
  stty raw -echo min 0 time 5

  printf '\0337\033[r\033[999;999H\033[6n\0338' > /dev/tty
  IFS='[;R' read -r _ rows cols _ < /dev/tty

  stty "$old"

  # echo "cols:$cols"
  # echo "rows:$rows"
  stty cols "$cols" rows "$rows"
}

res2() {

  old=$(stty -g)
  stty raw -echo min 0 time 5

  printf '\033[18t' > /dev/tty
  IFS=';t' read -r _ rows cols _ < /dev/tty

  stty "$old"

  # echo "cols:$cols"
  # echo "rows:$rows"
  stty cols "$cols" rows "$rows"
}
```

- `res` is based on the solution presented at https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/working_with_the_serial_console#Resizing_a_terminal. It works as follows:

  1. The cursor position is saved (`\0337`, [`DECSC`](http://www.vt100.net/docs/vt510-rm/DECSC.html)).
  2. The cursors is moved to the most bottom-right point possible (`\033[r\033[999;999H`, [`DECSTBM`](http://www.vt100.net/docs/vt510-rm/DECSTBM.html)? + [`CUP`](http://www.vt100.net/docs/vt510-rm/CUP.html)).
  3. The cursor position is reported (`\033[6n`, [`DSR`](http://www.vt100.net/docs/vt510-rm/DSR.html)).
  4. The cursor is moved back to the previously saved position (`\0338`, [`DECRC`](http://www.vt100.net/docs/vt510-rm/DECRC.html)).
- `res2` is influenced by `resize.sh` from xterm (see https://github.com/ThomasDickey/xterm-snapshots/blob/master/vttests/resize.sh). It uses a specific `xterm` code for getting the information we want (implemented in many terminal emulators), see: http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Functions-using-CSI-_-ordered-by-the-final-character_s_ (*"Report the size of the text area in characters."*).

BTW, in my `.profile` file you will find the following:
`[ $(tty) = /dev/ttyS0 ] && res`
so that the the terminal size is determined on every login over the serial line (the one I use for management), e.g. after you reboot the device.
See also the idea by *[rsaw](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/14833/rsaw)* in the comments to have the line `[ $(tty) = /dev/ttyS0 ] && trap res2 DEBUG` there instead so the resizing runs after every command (note that AFAIK it's not or not always possible on `busybox` though).

Comment: PS: To make more permanent, add `[[ $(tty) == /dev/ttyS0 ]] && trap res2 DEBUG` to one of the shell profile configs (e.g., `/etc/profile`,`~/.bash_profile`). This will make it be run after every single command (which would only be a good thing if you're resizing windows/panes with screen/tmux/terminal-emulator).

Comment: After using it for a few mins I quickly realized that both `res` & `res2` are too slow for anything but use on first-login. On my machines, they're both taking 0.5sec to finish ... making all my commands appear sluggish (when used with DEBUG trap). Whoops! Can't have that. Guess I'll be installing `xterm`.

Comment: @phk xterm's `resize` is waaaay faster -- usually 0.002sec.

Comment: @rsaw Oh OK, good to know, I thought it would behave similar and therefore be similarly slow. I remember that the one in some `busybox`es seemed to be just as slow to me.

Comment: Thanks for this standalone solution.  I'm using a console-only distro that does not have x11 or xterm installed so `resize` is not an option.

Comment: @thom_nic, FWIW, on Fedora, `resize` is packaged as `xterm-resize` that doesn't have any X11 dependencies. Thus, it should be fine for console-only distributions.

Comment: For anyone using GNU screen to serial console into a Raspberry Pi, I have found that the `res` function here works, while the `res2` function does not. Using iTerm2 on macOS 10.15.5

Comment: This is just a perfect answer for me. I'm using this in an anaconda script to create `/etc/profile.d/term_rezise.sh` which will run res2 on login. Brilliant

Answer (score 20):

Just for the record, here is the answer to this Problem (Usenet won):

Console Applications running inside virtual terminal applications (`xterm`, `rxvt` and friends) will receive `SIGWINCH` after a resize operation has taken place. Thus the application will be able to redraw the window etc. in the corresponding signal handler.

Unfortunately when using a serial console, there is no such mechanism.

It is however possible for the application to actively ask for the *current* console Window size. So the second best thing is to do this every time a command prompt is printed by the shell.

This can be achieved by first [compiling a special resize executable](http://web.archive.org/web/20081224152013/http://www.davehylands.com/gumstix-wiki/resize/resize.c) and then using the following in `bashrc`:

```
if [ $(tty) == '/dev/ttyS0' ]; then
  trap resize DEBUG
fi
```

Of course this will not change the console size settings in a console application during runtime.

Comment: Shouldn’t it be possible to run a protocol over the serial line, that *does* offer all the features? I mean we do have a client and a server. They could use inband escape sequences to do just about everything, and still work with a plain text serial console!

Comment: Actually, the comment in the code makes it plain that it's not the version of `resize` which is installed on your system.

Answer (score 15):

"Resizable" terminals as such are a result of NAWS (***`Negotiate About Window Size`*** from [RFC 1073](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1073.txt) *Telnet Window Size Option*).

If you are connected directly to the computer using a serial port, there is no negotiation involved, and the computer has no direct knowledge of your terminal's screen-size.

If a terminal can negotiate the size, the computer will send `SIGWINCH` to applications running in the terminal, telling them to update their notion of the screensize.

When the computer does not know the screensize, it typically sets the size shown by `stty -a` (rows and columns) to zero.  For interactive use, this is a little unfriendly, and some systems use environment variables `LINES` and `COLUMNS` to help.  The values assigned *may* be derived from the terminal description; more often they are simply hardcoded.  The convention for these variables requires that they take effect unless explicitly suppressed, e.g., in curses applications [`use_env`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_util.3x.html#h3-use_env) function. On the positive side, those variables can be useful when no reliable information is available.  On the negative side, there is no convenient method for altering those variables.

The [`resize`](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/resize.html) program (a utility provided with [`xterm`](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.html)) can use the VT100-style cursor position report escape sequence for determining the screen size.  This can be run from the command-line; there is (again) no convenient way to do it automatically.  As a side-effect, `resize` updates the information on rows/columns seen by `stty`.  Its use for providing updated environment variables is mainly useful for cases such as this, where `LINES` and `COLUMNS` *are* set, and should be updated.

Answer (score 3):

When running a shell session over a serial line it is sufficient to call the `resize` command inside that session - after establishing the connection and after each terminal geometry change.

The `resize` command is part of xterm but doesn't depend on X11. For example, on Fedora it's separately packaged as `xterm-resize`.

How it works: the resize command measures the height/width via some cursor movements and then sends those values to the terminal via escape sequences.

With a shell like zsh this also automagically updates the `LINES` and `COLUMNS` variables (alternatively, one can evaluate the export statements the commands prints to stdout).

Why this is necessary: with a local or ssh session the terminal is able to signal the session about geometry changes (cf. SIGWINCH). This mechanism doesn't work over a serial connection.

Answer (score 3):

Here is simple and fast resize function that works only for bash. It is modified from phk's res2, making use of bash's `read -d delim` to avoid letting the timeout to finish read.

```bsh
resize() {
  old=$(stty -g)
  stty -echo
  printf '\033[18t'
  IFS=';' read -d t _ rows cols _
  stty "$old"
  stty cols "$cols" rows "$rows"
}
```

Comment: As the resize command in Debian (and therefore also in RaspiOS and Ubuntu) is still part of the xterm package many years after someone added a patch to Debians bug tracking system this is now my preferred solution for a headless Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution that worked great for me on my embedded Linux system (Overo running Angstrom). I just ran it from my .bashrc file. I didn't want to use resize because that requires installing some X packages, and I didn't want that.

[Telling your Raspberry Pi that your terminal is bigger than 24 lines | Shallow Thoughts Blog](http://shallowsky.com/blog/tags/embedded/)

Comment: Please don't just post a link: include the relevant detail so that the information is available here as well...

Comment: Too bad it needs Python.

Comment: Not only is this not an answer, it is also not a link to an answer. It is a link to a page that links to an answer, that is effectively just a python implementation of the `res` function from the top voted answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/283206/9745

Answer (score 2):

While the `resize` command worked for me (`stty` manipulations were horribly slow), apparently `resize` in `DEBUG` trap messes up shell pipes.

Here is the solution I’ve ended up using. It runs `resize` after the prompt, but before the first command in pipe, unlike plain `DEBUG` hook that would run for each subcommand in `foo | bar | baz`.

Note that we can’t just put `resize` in `PROMPT_COMMAND` because it runs when the prompt is printed and it didn’t work well in my Vim "^Z+fg"-based workflow.

1. Resize terminal window while in Vim.
2. `^Z` (suspend job).
3. `PROMPT_COMMAND` executes and enables `DEBUG` hook (that would be triggered on next command).
4. Sometimes I adjust window size again at this point. That’s exactly why I can’t use `PROMPT_COMMAND` alone.
5. Type `fg` or `ls | cat` and hit enter.
6. `DEBUG` hook fires once and disables itself until the next prompt.
7. Shell runs user input.

```bash
if [ "$(tty)" = /dev/ttyS0 ]; then  
        # Run resize only after prompt so that we don’t
        # mess up pipes and other things.
        debug_hook_resize() {
                if [ -n "${debug_hook_prompt+x}" ]; then
                        unset debug_hook_prompt
                        resize 2>&1 >/dev/null
                fi
        }
        prompt_hook_resize() {
                debug_hook_prompt=
        }
        PROMPT_COMMAND=prompt_hook_resize
        trap debug_hook_resize DEBUG
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you could use FreeBSD instead, there's the [resizewin(1) command](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?resizewin), which does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Improving upon [Sven Geggus answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/19265/451977):

> This can be achieved by *first compiling a special resize executable and then* using the following in bashrc

A simple output redirection makes the gnu `resize` command works.
Just add the following to your `.bashrc`:

```bsh
alias rsz='resize >/dev/null'
if [ $(tty) == '/dev/ttyS0' ]; then
  trap rsz DEBUG
fi
```

In other words, you do not need a special `resize` command.

Answer (score 0):

I use this for Serial Gadget (based on phk's answer).
Calling resize only once per line.

```
sudo nano .profile
```

add:

```bsh
# resize function for connected serial console
resize() {
  old=$(stty -g)
  stty raw -echo min 0 time 5

  printf '\0337\033[r\033[999;999H\033[6n\0338' > /dev/tty
  IFS='[;R' read -r _ rows cols _ < /dev/tty

  stty "$old"

  #echo "cols:$cols"
  #echo "rows:$rows"
  stty cols "$cols" rows "$rows"
}

ALL_COMMANDS_FINISHED=1

PreCommands() {
  if [ "$ALL_COMMANDS_FINISHED" = '1' ]; then
    ALL_COMMANDS_FINISHED=0
    resize
    #echo "1->0"
  fi
}

PostCommands() {
  ALL_COMMANDS_FINISHED=1
}
  
# if login thru tty*
if [ $(tty) = /dev/tty* ]; then
  # PreCommands is called before every single command on a command line
  trap PreCommands DEBUG
  # PostCommands is called after all commands on a command line are finished
  PROMPT_COMMAND="PostCommands"
fi
```