# tty not resizing properly

Tags: linux, embedded

I'm running an embedded poky linux (linux-yocto v3.13) on a beagleboard. However, I'm having trouble when logging in over a serial using PuTTY: the terminal does not resize at all.
Usually, the terminal resizes automatically when the PuTTY windows is resized. Not so in my case. The terminal stays at 80x24.

dmesg says

```
[    0.000000] Console: colour dummy device 80x30
```

at the beginning. However, when I start e.g. nano right after boot, it's actually 80x24.

When I do

```
stty columns 200
stty rows 50
reset
```

manually, the terminal still stays at 80x24. However, the stty changes do carry over when using a program, e.g. nano. So nano will be the correct size (200x50), but the actual terminal will stay small.

SET yields (even after the stty commands above!)

```
COLUMNS=80
LINES=24
PS1='\u@\h:\w\$ '
```

Now, I wouldn't have a problem with 80 columns per sé. However, long commands don't wrap to the next line, they just overwrite the beginning of the current line for some reason.

```
opqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijkl^Cmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmn
```

I googled far and wide and the only "answers" that came up had to do with PS1 containing stray color codes that throw off the width calculation. However, that's not the case here.

I'd much appreciate some help in this matter, as I'm losing my sanity over this...

Answer (score 2):

The cases where you do see resizing are likely telnet or ssh-connections where NAWS (negotiate about window size: [RFC-1073](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1073.html)) is supported.

A *serial* connection doesn't do that.  It is a direct connection.  As a workaround, you can run the [`resize`](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/resize.html) program, like **this**:

```
resize
```

Further reading:

- [resizable serial console window?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16578/resizable-serial-console-window)