# Screen/Minicom multiline problem

Tags: terminal, gnu-screen, minicom

I'm managing with some boards like Arduino/UDOO etc. but I always face an annoying problem with minicom or screen.
If i type a long command, for example:

```
sudo /sbin/wpa_supplicant -s -B -P /run/wpa_supplicant.wlan0.pid -i wlan0 -D nl80211 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

it reaches the end of terminal window, instead of continuing in a new line, it overwrites over the same line.

[image: Overwriting]

One another annoying problem is when I up/down commands with UP/DOWN arrows. Check this gif while I up/down among last commands:

[image]

This is my env:

```
XDG_SESSION_ID=c1
TERM=linux
SHELL=/bin/bash
HUSHLOGIN=FALSE
USER=udooer
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.axa=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
MAIL=/var/mail/udooer
LC_MESSAGES=POSIX
PWD=/home/udooer
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
NODE_PATH=/usr/lib/nodejs:/usr/lib/node_modules:/usr/share/javascript
HOME=/home/udooer
SHLVL=2
LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
LOGNAME=udooer
LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
_=/usr/bin/env
```

checkwinsize is ON.

Even nano is resized to a minipage in top-left of the bigger screen :/

How to solve it?

Comment: Would wrap help with the first question? `minicom --color=on --wrap`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to manually execute `stty cols ... rows ...` and/or export `LINES` and `COLUMNS` to set the remote side's belief about the size to the terminal's actual size. Unfortunately there's no way this could be set automatically over a serial line.

Answer (score 0):

After establishing the serial connection you have to execute `resize` in that session. (Also, call `resize` again after each geometry change.)

This command [automatically detects](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/428764/1131) the right terminal geometry and notifies the shell about it.

On Fedora, the command is packaged as `xterm-resize` but doesn't depend on X11.