# resize putty window to default

Tags: putty, window, size

I want to resize a PuTTY window to its default (e.g. 32x120). Typically I enlarge the window with the mouse in one dimension. Afterward I want to resize it to its “default” again. Of course I can resize the window with the mouse but it is a little painful to get it somehow right. I am looking for a solution which for example I can put on a function key.

If I double click on the upper window boarder the window is maximized. Doing it again it restores the last size.

I tried also with the package `xterm` the resize command `resize -s 32 120` but I just get a time out: `resize: Time out occurred`. Maybe it is due to the fact that PuTTY doesn’t support (fully?) xterm. The variable `TERM` is set to `xterm`

My question is, is there a trick how I can resize the window to the default values. With default I mean the size when I created the window or a defined number of columns and rows.

I am working on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Note that solutions without the `xterm` package also exist: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/283206

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PuTTY recognizes the feature used by `resize`, but its dialog can disable it, giving the result you report.  That is *"Disable remote-controlled terminal resizing"* in the *"Terminal/Features"* tab.

Also, if you happen to be running in `screen` or `tmux`, those can interfere with the `resize` program.  As a workaround, detaching from those programs temporarily works for me.

Further reading:

- [10 Awesome PuTTY Tips and Tricks You Probably Didn’t Know](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/07/10-practical-putty-tips-and-tricks-you-probably-didnt-know/)

Comment: The `Disable remote-controlled terminal resizing` is not marked. Thanks for the tips but they don't seem to help.