# Why remote console doesn't use the whole terminal size

Tags: ssh, terminal, size

I have Linux mint 18, the remote machine have Ubuntu 16.04.
When I setup remote session via `ssh` sometimes it is broken:

[image]

As you can see it is restricted by 80x40, but I expect it should take full screen

[image]

Sometimes it takes full window, sometimes not.

How to fix that? it should take whole window always.

**UPD**

I miss major information. I `ssh` on host then I enter into container:

```
`kubectl --namespace=$NAMESPACE exec -ti `kubectl --namespace=$NAMESPACE get pods | grep $NAME | cut -f 1 -d ' '` bash`
```

**UPD**

```
$ gnome-terminal --version
GNOME Terminal 3.18.3
```

A terminal emulator for the GNOME desktop Using VTE version 0.42.5 +GNUTLS

**UPD**

```
stty size
0 0
```

Comment: This probably has to do with the environment variable `TERM`, and with the corresponding `terncap` / `terminfo` entry. What is different wen you run into the problem?

Comment: @SatoKatsura, probably you mean `termcap/terminfo` (terMcap)

Comment: @RomeoNinov I'm notoriously bad at typing. _shrug_

Comment: @SatoKatsura: I do not know. I save output from `ENV` and compare them when this problem occur. I will update question with that info. Thanks

Comment: Try `eval resize`.

Comment: @dirkt: `bash: resize: command not found`, but window resizing helps

Comment: On Debian, `resize` is part of the `xterm` package, I assume it's the same on Ubuntu.

Comment: What terminal emulator are you using? Does `stty size` print the correct size before and after running ssh?

Comment: You could try my solution from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/283206/117599 or `busybox`' `resize` instead of the one from the `xterm` package but normally it should not be required on `ssh` since the window resize signal normally works there fine.

Comment: @Gilles: `stty size -> 0 0`

Comment: @phk: I have updated question with info about `ssh`

Comment: Usually problems negotiating window size reflect an authentication problem with the connection (unlikely with ssh), but also a problem with the terminal client (which one, which version are not apparent from the question).  For the latter, that would be handled via bug-reporting systems...

Comment: @ThomasDickey: question updated

Comment: Most likely `kubectl` is the culprit. You can easily confirm by running `stty size` or `mc` after `ssh`ing but before launching `kubectl`, they should work correctly. I'm not familiar with `kubectl` but I guess it connects to a getty on a serial port or something like that, which by design cannot transfer "meta-data" such as the window size, only the actual bytes to be processed by the terminal emulator.

Comment: @egmont: But, as I said before. The `0 0` size returned not always.